# Golang Charmap decoder does not work in a container

Tags: go, encoding

I show DB2 data on my UI application. Backend service connects to the DB2 and gets data. DB2 had problems with Turkish characters("İ,ü,ç,ş") that's why I added a function which use Charmap package.

```
func decodeIso8859(byteSlice string) string {
    decoder := charmap.ISO8859_9.NewDecoder()
    decodedByteSlice, _ := decoder.String(byteSlice)
    return decodedByteSlice
}
```

When data returned from DB2 I decoded the data with above function. When ran directly on my host, it runs without any problem. However, when run the code in a container locally, it does not work. It does not gives any error just show "[]" or "\u001" instead of Turkish characters.

Comment: Forgetting kubernetes, have you ran the code _in a container_ locally?

Comment: No,  I did not run the code in a container locally.

Comment: It does not work in a container locally also.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] such as the input parameter and your Dockerfile